# Make activity appear in the 'wallpaper chooser'

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my activity to appear in the list of activities (gallery. live wallpapers, etc) that you see when you try to choose a wallpaper from the home screen.

Im assuming this is done with intents but cant seem to find one that works. The closest one I can find is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER>
```

but that doesn't work and seems to be used for something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be the intent-filter you want:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Defined here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER

(The DEFAULT category is a standard syntax for intents.)

Comment: Thanks! And yes I didn't put the DEFAULT category in all good now.

Comment: and how to hide?

Answer (score 1):

The list under 'select wallpaper from' dialogue box that pops up when you click 'wallpapers' from the homescreen has three entries on most phones (I checked stock and HTC Sense):

- Live wallpapers
- Gallery
- Wallpapers (or: HTC wallpapers)

When I press 'wallpapers' from the homescreen on HTC Sense I get:

```
09-26 20:17:58.901: INFO/ActivityManager(104): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER_DIALOG cmp=com.htc.launcher/.WallpaperChooserDialog (has extras) }
09-26 20:17:59.301: INFO/ActivityManager(104): Displayed activity com.htc.launcher/.WallpaperChooserDialog: 353 ms (total 353 ms)
```

When on stock:

```
09-26 20:19:41.231: INFO/ActivityManager(86): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) }
09-26 20:19:41.571: INFO/ActivityManager(86): Displayed activity android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity: 294 ms (total 294 ms)
```

And when I click through on 'wallpapers' when on stock:

```
09-26 20:19:51.101: INFO/ActivityManager(86): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.WallpaperChooser }
09-26 20:19:51.581: INFO/ActivityManager(86): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.WallpaperChooser: 463 ms (total 463 ms)
```

You need to use android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER. Maybe you forgot some other implementation details such as

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

so the chooser could pick it up? Have a look at Photostream's source code (http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/Photostream). Romain Guy has it working.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can not set activities as a wallpaper. You have to create a [`Live Wallpaper`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html) instead, and draw your content on a `SurfaceView` using a `Canvas`. You may create views yourself there in order to draw them on the canvas manually, but that is a little tricky and in most of the cases not what you want.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to set an activity as a wallpaper. I want my app/activity to be an item that is listed under 'select wallpaper from' dialogue box that pops up when you click 'wallpapers' from the homescreen.